# Deploying ReactJS (w/ webpack) to S3 & CloudFront

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, webpack, amazon-cloudfront

I have a ReactJS application that produces a `dist` folder when I perform an `npm build`. This can be uploaded to Amazon's S3 and everything is fine.

I'm looking to continuously deploy this application, so my thoughts were to deploy to `s3://RANDOM_STRING/`, producing:

`RANDOM_STRING/js
RANDOM_STRING/css
RANDOM_STRING/index.html`

I can't tell S3, to the best of my knowledge, to use a sub-directory as a web-root, so I looked into CloudFront and updating the origin to the directory. This takes a lot of time to update and actually can't be done through the `aws-cli`, so continuous deployment would be ruined.

I've looked at using `file-loader` to rewrite my `url()` calls to include the `RANDOM_STRING` into the deployment assets, but this feels pretty "ugly"

Does anyone have experience of this kind of deployment and could help me out?

Comment: Is RANDOM_STRING the bucket name, or a path within bucket?

Comment: A path within the bucket

Comment: I guess I could always deploy to a new bucket and change the DNS, but that doesn't feel correct either :)

Comment: We deploy using CI to an S3 bucket, but just overwrite the existing files in the bucket, although any js assets have cachebusting filenames anyway. Run cloudfront in front of the bucket with custom ssl cert.

Comment: So you'll need to ask Cloudfront to invalidate index.html? How do you clean up old deployments?

Comment: A little dirty, but we set short cache headers on the index file. Use a script to prune old releases. The amazon "cloud formation" way would be to spin up a new bucket & cloudfront distribution, upload new files and switch DNS like you suggest, but (for our needs) it's overkill.

Comment: Yeah, cloudformation would mean a 15/20 minute deployment time and I don't like that. Do you use cache busting names on image assets too?

Comment: Yes basically all js, css & other assets are served from a cache busting dir name. It's generally only the index file that has the same path for obvious reasons. You can work round some of the limitations either by careful manipulation of cache headers on objects or by adding behaviour rules for selected paths in the CF distribution settings.

Comment: OK. Thanks @rbaker86

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your Default Root Object? You can configure it to be a sub directory.

See here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DefaultRootObject.html

Comment: Then my users would see `https://myapp.com/hfsdjkhfjskhfjsk/index.html` and I'd prefer to avoid that

Comment: I see what you mean... I think you may be pushing the boundries of S3 at this point and would need to consider an EC2 instance (for finer control over the web server)